# Trying to exit main command from a piped grep condition

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pipe

I'm struggling to find a good solution for what I'm trying to do.

So I have a CreateReactApp instance that is booted through a `yarn run start:e2e`. As soon as the output from that command has "Compiled successfully", I want to be able to run next command in the bash script.

Different things I tried:

```
if yarn run start:e2e | grep "Compiled successfully"; then
  exit 0
fi
echo "THIS NEEDS TO RUN"
```

This does appear to stop the logs, but it does not run the next command.

```
yarn run start:e2e | while read -r line;
do
  echo "$line"
  if [[ "$line" == *"Compiled successfully!"* ]]; then
    exit 0
  fi
done
echo "THIS NEEDS TO RUN"
```

```
yarn run start:e2e | grep -q "Compiled successfully";
echo $?
echo "THIS NEEDS TO RUN"
```

I've read about the differences between pipes / process substitions, but don't see a practical implementation regarding my use case..

Can someone enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: Because I got multiple proposed solutions and none of those worked I'll maybe redefine my main problem a bit.

1. So the `yarn run start:e2e` boots op a react app, that has a sort of "watch" mode. So it keeps spewing out logs after the "Compiled successfully" part, when changes occur to the source code, typechecks, ....
   After the React part is booted (so if the log Compiled succesfully is outputted) the logs do not matter anymore but the localhost:3000 (that the yarn compiles to) must remain active.
2. Then I run other commands after the yarn run to do some testing on the localhost:3000

So basically what I want to achieve in pseudo (the pipe stuff in command A is very abstract and may not even look like the correct solution but trying to explain thoroughly):

```
# command A
yarn run dev | cmd_to_watch_the_output "Compiled succesfully" | exit 0 -> localhost:3000 active but the shell is back in 'this' window

-> keep watching the output until Compiled succesfully occurs
-> If it occurs, then the logs does not matter anymore and I want to run command B

# command B
echo "I WANT TO SEE THIS LOG"
... do other stuff ...

I hope this clears it up a bit more :D 

Thanks already for the propositions!
```

Comment: This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556240/how-can-a-command-within-a-pipeline-abort-the-pipeline

Comment: What do you mean by `As soon as the output from that command has "Compiled successfully"`?  Whatever you hope that means, any buffering will almost certainly get in the way of what you're hoping to accomplish.  Are you not willing to simply wait for `yarn` to run to completion?

Comment: If you want `grep` to stop when it sees `Compiled successfully`, you want `grep -q` or `grep -m 1`. Otherwise, even though it only _prints_ the "Compiled successfully" line, it still keeps reading to the rest of `yarn run` output to see if there are more "Compiled successfully" lines later.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It never stops, it stays in "watch mode" or at least the stdout stays open.. So the command never "completes", no exit 0

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll try to add the -q & -m 1 :D Thanks! I'll keep you posted!

Comment: One or the other, not both. `-q` _both_ does `-m 1` and also suppresses output; so if you're streaming the logs some other way or don't want _any_ logs to be visible, then you want the `-q`; if you want to print only the success line and none of the logs leading up to it, then you want the `-m 1`.

Comment: Are you trying to kill the `yarn` while it is still running? When it produces the output of "Compiled successfully", kill it then run/do something else?

Comment: @Darkman, ...that's how I read it. As long as yarn treats as EPIPE as fatal and actually goes on to write at least one more line after "Compiled successfully", grep exiting should be enough to kill it.

Comment: @PsykoMantrix, ...by contrast, if you want `yarn run` to keep running _in the background_ after that line is seen, without bad things happening next time it wants to log another line to stdout, that'll take more work.

Comment: *After the React part is booted (so if the log Compiled succesfully is outputted) the logs do not matter anymore but the localhost:3000 (that the yarn compiles to) must remain active.* -- okay, _that's_ a huge difference; removes the first two of the three approaches from consideration, and will require some changes on the 3rd.

Comment: Edited to remove the approaches that don't work at all in light of updated requirements, and to extend the one that does. Note that I could have asked you to re-ask the question (changing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers that were correct as it was originally asked is bad form here); in the future, please try to set out your expectations up-front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `yarn run` to keep running even after `Compiled successfully`, you can't just pipe its stdout to another program that exits after that line: that stdout needs to have somewhere to go so `yarn`'s future attempts to write logs don't fail or block.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[0-3].*|4.[012].*) echo "Error: bash 4.3+ required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

exec {yarn_fd}< <(yarn run); yarn_pid=$!
while IFS= read -r line <&$yarn_fd; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  if [[ $line = *"Compiled successfully!"* ]]; then
    break
  fi
done
# start a background process that reads future stdout from `yarn run`
cat <&$yarn_fd >/dev/null & cat_pid=$!
# close the FD from that background process so `cat` has the only copy
exec {yarn_fd}<&-

echo "Doing other things here!"
echo "When ready to shut down yarn, kill $yarn_pid and $cat_pid"
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation! Gave me more insights on the different approaches. Will try it out tomorrow :]

Comment: So I tried your first solution (with tee /dev/stderr, and once with the tee /dev/stdout). I do get the message "Compiled successfully!" but does not trigger the "'Running this after "Compiled successfully" was seen'". I'll try your second solution :D

Comment: Same with the second solution, it stays on the "Compiled successful" but does not goes to the second command

Comment: I editted my original question to try to explain my problem more thoroughly ;D Thanks already for the time tho!

Comment: Obviously, I don't have your javascript project, so i can't test behavior of `yarn run` in the exact same context. However, take a look at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/InfiniteExoticBug#main.sh -- the "must be reached" line really is reached.

Comment: Or there's https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/AutomaticImperturbableResearch#main.sh, showing the 2nd approach working

Comment: Or there's https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/PhysicalDifferentPatches#main.sh, showing the 1st approach working

Comment: @PsykoMantrix, ...mind, what all of these have in common is that in the example I'm using as a stand-in for the code you have yarn invoking, *Compiled successfully* isn't the last line of output. I explained in the comments on the question why that matters -- it's the next time `yarn` tries to write a line of output _after_ `grep` exited that it gets an EPIPE notifying it to shut down, so if there's no more output after that point then only the 3rd approach will work.